# ERROR-HANDLING not working

Tags: python

My error-handling code is not working. I'm trying to do following: if user enters  any input other than 1, 2 or 3, then the user should get error message and the while-loop should start again.

However my code is not working. Any suggestion why?

```
def main():
print("")
while True:
    try:
        number=int(input())
        if number==1:
            print("hei")
        if number==2:
            print("bye")
        if number==3:
            print("hei bye")
        else:
            raise ValueError
except ValueError:
    print("Please press 1 for hei, 2 for bye and 3 for hei bye")

 main()
```

Comment: What is the error message? Also your indenting is all wrong and would cause serious syntax issues. Can you fix that?

Comment: Make sure your `except` is indented to the same level as your `try`?

Comment: why do you need the try ... except in the first place?

Comment: also, this is an infinite loop ...

Comment: @JulienSpronck because `int` will raise a `ValueError` upon non convertible inputs from `input()` - but yes, it does require a break :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use exception handling a bit more nicely here to handle this case, eg:

```
def main():
    # use a dict, so we can lookup the int->message to print
    outputs = {1: 'hei', 2: 'bye', 3: 'hei bye'}
    print() # print a blank line for some reason
    while True:
        try:
            number = int(input()) # take input and attempt conversion to int
            print(outputs[number]) # attempt to take that int and print the related message
        except ValueError: # handle where we couldn't make an int
            print('You did not enter an integer')
        except KeyError: # we got an int, but couldn't find a message
            print('You entered an integer, but not, 1, 2 or 3')
        else: # no exceptions occurred, so all's okay, we can break the `while` now
            break

main()
```